# Which function whose graph looks like the space time around a black hole?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

What function has a graph that looks like this but i just want 2 dimensions [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\ln(|x|)$$ where $\ln$ is the logarithmic function to the base $e$, and $|x|$ is the absolute value of $x$.

[image: Graph of the function $\ln(|x|)$]

Comment: the graph have good resemblance with space time around black hole but the image you showed of graph ln(|x|) is ugly !!

Comment: @alugnis-eloh You can't expect it to look like Mona Lisa

Comment: @alugnis-eloh That was just a screen-shot from Wolfram|Alpha, I would be happy if someone could render the graph of the function in question with *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a simple function of the form :$$\dfrac{-k}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$

[Graph example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-100/%28x%5E2%2by%5E2%29)

Comment: Graph of it please!

Comment: and is k a variable or a constant?

Comment: @alugnis-eloh , updated